# Continuously differentiable approximation of indicator function on interval $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I am trying to determine a continuously differentiable approximation of the indicator function of an interval $[a,b]$ given by:
 $$I(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & \quad x \in [a,b] \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$
I know that for the indicator function of $\mathbb{R_+}$, the slightly modified logistic function given by:
 $$L(x,\nu) = \frac{1}{1+\exp\left((-\nu \left(x+\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{\nu}}\right)\right)}$$
does the trick. However, I am having difficulties seeing how this function could be adapted to the case of an interval $[a,b]$? Any ideas or comments would be greatly appreciated.

edit: thanks to the remark below by Wojowu, we can use:
 $$L(x,\nu) = \frac{1}{\left(1+\exp\left((-\nu \left(x-a+\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{\nu}}\right)\right)\right)\left(1+\exp\left((-\nu \left(b-x+\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{\nu}}\right)\right)\right)},$$
and this seems to work.

Comment: Hint: $x\in(a,b)$ iff $x-a\in\Bbb R_+$ and $b-x\in\Bbb R_+$ (since we approximate anyways, we can replace closed interval with an open one)

Comment: @Wojowu thanks for your input. Yes I had considered this, but the problem is how to combine the joint conditions in the exponential appearing in the denominator?

Comment: Multiplying the two indicator functions should work.

Comment: You haven't defined "approximation" nor "does the trick"

Comment: @zhw. what I mean by approximation is that $\lim_{\nu \to \infty} L(x,\nu) = I(x)$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, Does there seem to be something wrong with the suggested function?

Comment: No, no problem. Looks good, I just wanted to know what the terms meant.